# Time Complexity for a specific nested for loop

Tags: time, big-o, complexity-theory

I am looking for the time complexity (big O) for the following nested loop.
Given an array A[] with size n.

```
for (i=1; i<=n/2; i++){
    for(j=i; j<=n-i; j++){
        print (A[j]);
    }
}
```

In this problem A is indexed at 1. so the first element of A[] is A[1].

Answer (score 2):

Since the innermost execution time is constant, we have
[image]

So `T(n) is O(n^2)`